# Unable to find csrss.exe

Tags: c#, .net, windows, powershell

I'm trying to digitally verify some windows processes, one of which is csrss.exe.

I have tried 2 techniques, the first being this:

```
IntPtr phCertStore = IntPtr.Zero;
IntPtr phMsg = IntPtr.Zero;
IntPtr ppvContext = IntPtr.Zero;
int pdwMsgAndCertEncodingType = 0;
int pdwContentType = 0;
int pdwFormatType = 0;
if (!Crypt32.CryptQueryObject(
    Wincrypt.CERT_QUERY_OBJECT_FILE,
    @"C:\windows\system32\csrss.exe",
    Wincrypt.CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_ALL,
    Wincrypt.CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_FLAG_ALL,
    0,
    ref pdwMsgAndCertEncodingType,
    ref pdwContentType,
    ref pdwFormatType,
    ref phCertStore,
    ref phMsg,
    ref ppvContext
))
{
    Console.WriteLine((new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error())).Message);
    Console.ReadLine();
    return;
}
int pcbData = 0;
if (!Crypt32.CryptMsgGetParam(phMsg, Wincrypt.CMSG_ENCODED_MESSAGE, 0, null, ref pcbData))
{
    Console.WriteLine((new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error())).Message);
    Console.ReadLine();
    return;
}
byte[] pvData = new byte[pcbData];
Crypt32.CryptMsgGetParam(phMsg, Wincrypt.CMSG_ENCODED_MESSAGE, 0, pvData, ref pcbData);
var signedCms = new SignedCms();
signedCms.Decode(pvData);
try
{
    signedCms.CheckSignature(false);
    Console.WriteLine("Signature check passed");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
finally
{
    Crypt32.CryptMsgClose(phMsg);
    Crypt32.CertCloseStore(phCertStore, 0);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

and the second being this:

```
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe", $"Get-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath " + "\"C:\\windows\\system32\\csrss.exe\"");
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();

string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

However, both of these are saying file not found! The exact same powershell arguments copied into another powershell instance WORKS! If I change any of the paths to another signed file, it works!
I even tried running as Admin but still file not found!
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you project settings?  Make sure x64 is unchecked and x86 is checked.

Comment: If your process is 32-bit, it won't find that file because it doesn't exist in `SysWOW64`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for this is using the correct bitness.